# Cannot get coordinates of simple success callback on getCurrentPosition function

Tags: angular, geolocation

The getUserLocation() fires as well as the if statement. The navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() function does not fire. I can't log anything inside that statement. I am not sure why nothing is happening..

Just logging in the arrow function. Nothing is showing there.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'google-map',
    templateUrl: './google-map.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./google-map.component.css']
})
export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit {

  lat: number;

      lng: number;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getUserLocation();

  }

   getUserLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( position => {
          this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
          this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      });
    }
  }

}
```

I need values for the lat/lng.

Comment: Doing this will first request location access from the user. If the user declines the access request, then you won't have access to the location.

Answer (score 0):

It requires that user consents to location sharing when
prompted by the browser.

If you see the error "The Geolocation service failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to locate you.

Check the api [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation#DetectingUserLocation).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use Asyn Await
Also Window.navigator

```
async getUserLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    await window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( position => {
          this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
          this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      });
    }
  }
```

in my app I use the below code

```
 async getlocation() {
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
     await window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          console.log(position);
          return position;
        },
        error => {
          switch (error.code) {
            case 1:
              console.log('Permission Denied');
              break;
            case 2:
              console.log('Position Unavailable');
              break;
            case 3:
              console.log('Timeout');
              break;
          }
        }
      );
    }

  }
```

Comment: I tried async and no luck. The issue has something to do with Chrome, I just tried Firefox and everything works with my original code.

Comment: geolocation from non-secure sites was deprecated. All sources say localhost should work, but it does not. Looks like I'm just going to use Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use browser geolocation, you need the user to give consent. Otherwise, the call to the `getCurrentPosition` will silently fail.
Also, if the user is running your webapp, from latest Google Chrome browser,  you will need your website to work on HTTPS.